# What does the "depth" mean on earth?

Tags: ros, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am really confused about the meaning of "depth" which is acquired by a RGB-D camera.
I think there are two meanings,

1: The distance from a point in the 3-D world to the infrared camera center.

2: The Z value of the 3-D world point in the camera frame.

Which is right?

If the second meaning is right, the depth values of all the points in a wall which is parallel with the RGB-D camera should be equal, but the fact is not like that. However, many 3-D vision books indicate the second meaning is right. I am really confused. Who can help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213856/what-does-the-%22depth%22-mean-on-earth?/) by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2015-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The data being provided should have a `frame_id` defined which will tell you which coordinate frame the data is referenced against.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1